# Canon T6 settings for Baptism and First Birthday

Tags: photography-basics

I just started photography and my Aunty caught my interest and wants me to photograph her son's baptism and 1st birthday party. I have a Canon T6 with a standard 18-55mm lens. What are the best settings to use and what type of photos should I be taking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prepare for my first event shoot (large corporate gathering) tomorrow?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61671/how-do-i-prepare-for-my-first-event-shoot-large-corporate-gathering-tomorrow)

Answer (score 9):

You should never attempt to be the principal photographer at a benchmark life event unless you have the needed skills. Fortunately the T6 has a mode dial and one of the setting is A+. Between now and this special day, read the camera manual and practice – practice. Use the fully auto setting, it will save your butt.

Comment: I don't disagree. But there is gobbldy gook. Often an inexperienced photographer is better than no photographer. An inexperienced photographer who cares about what settings to use will often produce better images than the people who don't. And a photographer with a T6 will often produce better images than people with their cell phones, though not always. Which is to say that 90% is just showing up...or rather pressing the shutter release with the lens cap off.

Comment: @ ben Rudgers -- Benchmark life events can't be repeated. We all do our best but sometimes even the best of us will fail. Hopefully, it won't be your benchmark event.